# how to get database current time using jooq API

Tags: java, sql, jooq

How to get the current database time using the jooq API. Is the below the right approach?

```
Record result = DSL.using(configuration).fetchOne("Select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as NOW");
Timestamp now = result.get("NOW", Timestamp.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) is always an option, but why not use what's available in jOOQ already, e.g. [`DSL.currentTimestamp()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#currentTimestamp--)

```java
Timestamp now = using(configuration)
               .select(currentTimestamp())
               .fetchOne(0, Timestamp.class);
```

Or even simpler:

```java
Timestamp now = using(configuration).fetchValue(select(currentTimestamp());
```

As always, these jOOQ queries assume you're using the following static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```